# Testing a redirect to a new Superdomain with Cypress

Tags: javascript, testing, cypress

I am testing an application that has a "Continue" button
This button has no href.
When I click "Continue", it triggers a POST and redirects it to another superdomain.

I tried solutions like those mentioned in the link: [Testing a redirect to a new route with Cypress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46839520/testing-a-redirect-to-a-new-route-with-cypress)

But it didn't work for me.

[image]

If I remove the "wait" after click, the following test fails with:

> Step implementation missing for

Comment: have tried to use `.click({ force: true })` ?

Comment: I hadn't tried it, but it doesn't change the behavior.
The problem is redirecting to another superdomain.

I don't know how to get the new url without having its href.

Comment: You can workaround it by disabling websecurity, though might not be recommended. See details at https://docs.cypress.io/guides/guides/web-security.html#Set-chromeWebSecurity-to-false

Comment: Unfortunately I am unable to run from Chrome due to another problem. :(
This setting only applies to Chrome.